# Assign the response times to each question in a Moodle questionnaire using groupby pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, moodle

I´m trying to assign the time it takes to answer each question from a Moodle post-Process log. I have organized the data in the following way

Example DATA (2 students and 4 questions)

```
original= [{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:00:00"},{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:01:00"},{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:02:00"},{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:04:00"},{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:05:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:00:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:02:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:04:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:04:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:05:00"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(original)
df['Send'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Send'], format='%H:%M:%S') - pd.to_datetime(df['Send'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.normalize()
df['diff'] = df.sort_values(['Student','Send']).groupby('Student')['Send'].diff()
df
   Send    Student     diff
0 00:00:00      S1      NaT
1 00:01:00      S1 00:01:00  # Send[1]-Send[0]= S1 Time response to P1
2 00:02:00      S1 00:01:00
3 00:04:00      S1 00:02:00
4 00:05:00      S1 00:01:00
5 00:00:00      S2      NaT
6 00:02:00      S2 00:02:00
7 00:04:00      S2 00:02:00
8 00:04:00      S2 00:00:00
9 00:05:00      S2 00:01:00
```

And I'm looking for a solution like this: a new dataframe that collects the student name and the time of response (Column diff) for each question. Something like that

```
  Student | P1      | P2      | P3      | P4      
 ---------|---------|---------|---------|--------- 
  S1      | 0:01:00 | 0:01:00 | 0:02:00 | 0:01:00 
  S2      | 0:02:00 | 0:02:00 | 0:00:00 | 0:01:00
```

Considerations:

- in the example data, the first value of each student (index 0 for S1 and index 6 for S2)  is the time at which the question was displayed
- the second value for each student (index 2 for S1) is the moment the student saves the first answer.
- The response time is therefore 0:01:00 - 0:00:00 (Send[1]-Send[0])

I'm sure it's a simple problem, but right now I'm stuck and I don't know how to get out of this impasse. Any help will be welcome

Comment: Which Moodle log are you using?

Comment: hi, I`m using the log report CSV for the questionarie (as professor the only log I can access). I do some clean and transformations before obtain a "clean" log from the Time, User full name, Affected user, Event context, Component, Event name, Description, Origin, IP address 
original columns If you are interested in those steps, I can send you the code.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the 'diff' column to create a column of cumulative values that will be reset at 0. Group it with the 'Student' column and transform the table from there.

```
df['P_No'] = df['diff'].apply(lambda x: pd.NaT if pd.isnull(x) else 1).fillna(0)
df['P_No'] = df['P_No'].groupby((df['P_No']-df['P_No'].shift() !=0).cumsum()).cumsum()
df = df[df['diff'].notnull()].groupby(['Student','P_No'])['diff'].agg(sum).unstack()
df = df.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
new_col = [ c if c == 'Student' else 'P'+str(c) for c in df.columns]
df.columns = new_col
df

Student P1  P2  P3  P4
0   S1  00:01:00    00:01:00    00:02:00    00:01:00
1   S2  00:02:00    00:02:00    00:00:00    00:01:00
```